# jq: split one resultset to multiple json objects

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to transform one big json resultset to multiple objects.

Input:

```
{
  "results": {
    "2019-11-27 00:00:00": [
      {
        "e": "10814",
        "s": "153330",
        "t": "164144"
      }
    ],
    "2019-11-27 00:15:00": [
      {
        "e": "11052",
        "s": "148692",
        "t": "159744"
      }
    ],
    "2019-11-27 00:30:00": [
      {
        "e": "11550",
        "s": "152379",
        "t": "163929"
      }
    ],
    "2019-11-27 00:45:00": [
      {
        "e": "12640",
        "s": "154984",
        "t": "167624"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the output I'm trying to reach:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:00:00","e":"10814","s":"153330","t":"164144"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:15:00","e":"11052","s":"148692","t":"159744"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:30:00","e":"11550","s":"152379","t":"163929"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:45:00","e":"12640","s":"154984","t":"167624"}
```

I tried so far:

```
$ cat input.json | jq -cr '.[] | keys[] as $k | { "timestamp": "\($k)"}'
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:00:00"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:15:00"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:30:00"}
{"timestamp":"2019-11-27 00:45:00"}
```

and

```
$ cat input.json | jq -c '.[] | .[]  | .[]'
{"e":"10814","s":"153330","t":"164144"}
{"e":"11052","s":"148692","t":"159744"}
{"e":"11550","s":"152379","t":"163929"}
{"e":"12640","s":"154984","t":"167624"}
```

I just need a hint to combine these two filters to obtain the result as described above. I'm not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dmitry - thank you for the suggestion. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. Just add the objects in those arrays to objects you created out of keys.

```
.results | keys_unsorted[] as $k | { timestamp: $k } + .[$k][]
```

[Online demo with your sample](https://jqplay.org/s/1BeMW9tCtM)
[Online demo with a slightly different input to show what `+ .[$k][]` does clearly](https://jqplay.org/s/4v3Q6lVtyU)

Comment: nice example. the one with the different input was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `to_entries`:

```
.results
| to_entries[]
| { timestamp: .key } + .value[]
```